# Multiple aws s3 sync commands - order of operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We recently ran a disaster recovery exercise, and our servers are backed up in AWS S3.  So, I simply run sync commands to pull the data down from s3 to our servers.

I selected and simultaneously ran six commands, and noticed that they seemingly did not run chronologically in the order entered in the PowerShell window.

The reason I know this is because the SQL data, which was the last two commands listed, was available prior to some of the other synced items.

This leads me to wonder how s3 sync works.  When you run several commands at once, what is the protocol for how they are executed?

Comment: Can you show how you were running several commands at once exactly? They should not be aware of each other and block each other at all. Could it be that the ones that had the least amount of data to copy simply finished first?

Comment: What do you mean by "run chronologically"? Did each of the six commands just download one file?

Comment: @MarkB  Each command was a standard s3 sync command:

aws s3 sync <s3 path1> <local path1>
aws s3 sync <s3 path2> <local path2>
etc, etc.

Some were huge directories full of document backups
Some were huge SQL backups

In PowerShell, I highlighted each of them, and executed them, all at once.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein See above comment.  In PowerShell, I simply highlighted all of the commands and then executed them.  There were thousands of files in some cases, and just a couple huge SQL backups in the other cases.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something because I don't use Windows, but were they running in parallel or sequentially? Your description of "highlight and run" is really vague. Where you copy/pasting a list of commands into a single powershell terminal? Or copying each command into separate terminals?

Comment: @MarkB That is correct, a single powershell terminal.  Ultimately, I just have a powershell script file (.ps1), with all the commands already typed out.  So I just select/highlight all of them, then execute them.  I can see why my description of it would be confusing.  Technically, I don't even need to select/highlight them; if I wanted to run all of them, I could just execute the script.  Poor description, on my part.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the same, through my research I've learned that I am running the sync operations in parallel (not sequentially) by selecting and executing them simultaneously.  This explains the behavior we're seeing.

In one of Mark B's comments above, he eluded to this fact, and I missed it.

Comment: This is not definitely an answer to the question. You can add it as a comment.

Comment: Fair point.  Although I believe it answers it, as I asked what the protocol is for how they are executed, and the answer is it's parallel, not sequential.